# Oracle Join tables with range of dates in first table and dates in second table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have two tables in an Oracle database:

The first table has a date range and I need help in writing a SQL query to find all the records from second table as in the result table below. The first four digits in the date is year and last two are session (10-Fall; 20-Spring; 30-Summer).

1) Table1

```
seqnum |   min_date|   max_date |c_id  

1      | 201210    |    201210  |   100    
1      | 201220    |    201330  |   150    
1      | 201410    |    201410  |   200
```

2) Table2

```
seqnum |   b_date

1      | 201210
1      | 201220 
1      | 201230
1      | 201310
1      | 201320 
1      | 201330 
1      | 201410
1      | 201420 
1      | 201430
```

3) Result table

```
seqnum | b_date | c_id

1      | 201210 | 100
1      | 201220 | 150
1      | 201230 | 150
1      | 201310 | 150
1      | 201320 | 150
1      | 201330 | 150
1      | 201410 | 200
1      | 201420 | 200
1      | 201430 | 200
```

If `Table1` have only the first record then all the dates in `Table2` must be associated with `c_id` 100 only.

Comment: what is the relation betwwen table 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this as simply as possible:

```
select t2.seqnum, t2.b_date, coalesce(t1.c_id, t3.max_id) as c_id
  from table2 t2
  left outer join table1 t1
    on t2.b_date between t1.min_date and t1.max_date
  cross join (select max(c_id) as max_id from table1) t3
  order by t1.c_id, t2.b_date
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ef62/7)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45c72/10/0

```
select t2.seqnum,
       t2.b_date,
       case when t2.b_date < min_rg then x.c_id
            when t2.b_date > max_rg then y.c_id
              else t1.c_id
                end as c_id
  from (select min(min_date) as min_rg, max(max_date) as max_rg from table1) z
  join table1 x
    on x.min_date = z.min_rg
  join table1 y
    on y.max_date = z.max_rg
 cross join table2 t2
  left join table1 t1
    on t2.b_date between t1.min_date and t1.max_date
 order by b_date
```

When B_DATE on table2 is lower than the first MIN_DATE on table1 it will show C_ID from table1 of the lowest MIN_DATE (100 in your case, right now).

When B_DATE on table2 is higher than the last MAX_DATE on table1 it will show C_ID from table1 of the highest MAX_DATE (200 in your case, right now).

Answer (score 0):

```
with table1 as (
select 1 seqnum, 201210 min_date, 201210 max_date, 100 c_id from dual
union all select 1, 201220, 201330, 150 from dual
union all select 1, 201410, 201410, 200 from dual
),
table2 as (
select 1 seqnum, 201210 b_date from dual
union all select 1, 201220 from dual
union all select 1, 201230 from dual
union all select 1, 201310 from dual
union all select 1, 201320 from dual
union all select 1, 201330 from dual
union all select 1, 201410 from dual
union all select 1, 201420 from dual
union all select 1, 201430 from dual
),    
semi as (
select t2.seqnum, t2.b_date, t1.c_id, 
       -- since Oracle 11g   
       --lag(c_id IGNORE NULLS) over(partition by t2.seqnum order by t2.b_date) prev_c_id
       last_value(c_id IGNORE NULLS) over(partition by t2.seqnum 
                                          order by t2.b_date 
                                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                                   AND 1 PRECEDING) prev_c_id
from table2 t2 left join table1 t1
     on t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum and t2.b_date between t1.min_date and t1.max_date
) 
select seqnum, b_date, nvl(c_id, prev_c_id) c_id
from semi;
```

This can be done with analytic functions.

1. Left join Table2 with Table1
2. Calculate previous (rows are ordered by `b_date`) not null value of `c_id` with (`LAG` or `LAST_VALUE` + windowing) for each `seqnum`.
3. If c_id is NULL then show the first not null previous value.